# Execution Error - ERC20: Transfer Amount Exceeds Balance in Ethereum Smart Contract

Tags: erc-20, gas, gas-estimate, arbitrage

I'm encountering a perplexing issue while working on an Ethereum smart contract. It seems to be a parameter related error, but I haven't been able to rectify it. The following error message is displayed:

```
"Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted: ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance","id":6702872335081692}
```

Sometimes, it modifies slightly to "exceeds balance".

When I call the function, I'm using these parameters for a $1 arbitrage transaction:

```
usdtAmount: 1000000;
wbtcAmount: 8000;
```

Interestingly, when I input 0 for both usdt and wbtc amount, the transaction gets fully reverted.

Here's the code snippet of the function I am trying to call:

```
function approveAndPerformArbitrage(
    uint usdtAmount,
    uint wbtcAmount,
    address[] calldata path1,
    address[] calldata path2
) external {
    // Approve the Uniswap and Sushiswap contracts to spend the necessary tokens
    usdtContract.safeApprove(address(uniswap), usdtAmount);
    usdtContract.safeApprove(address(sushiswap), usdtAmount);
    wbtcContract.safeApprove(address(uniswap), wbtcAmount);
    wbtcContract.safeApprove(address(sushiswap), wbtcAmount);

    // Call the performArbitrage function
    performArbitrage(usdtAmount, wbtcAmount, path1, path2);
}
```

I've also tried using gas estimation to circumvent this problem as suggested by some, but it didn't seem to work. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!